# Accumulate Observables from different Streams for polling

Tags: java, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm trying to accumulate Observables from  server calls, for then flatmapping them and make another server call.

```
private Observable poll(Observable<TaskStatus> taskObservable) {
     Observable.add(taskObservable) //Pseudocode
    .buffer(3 sec) 
    .flatMap(...)
    ...
}
```

How can the Observable accumulation ("add") be achieved?

Comment: Could you give an example of desired input and output?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the **merge()** operator.

For more information on combining Observables, see this: https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables

Comment: The merge is great, if you have two (or more) existing Observables at the same time.Observable.merge(observable1, observable2); it's like calling ListUtils.union(list1, list2); But I wanna add them one by one to an "Empty Observable". Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I added another answer regarding Composite Disposable/Subscription.  Hopefully that's what you're looking for instead?

Answer (score 0):

For accumulation then, I think you might be after something like the **CompositeDisposable** that is part of Rx.NET.

Sample Rx.NET usage: http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/disposables#toc2

Documentation for Rx.NET class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.compositedisposable(v=vs.103).aspx

I believe the Rx Java equivalent is the **CompositeSubscription** class.

See here:  http://netflix.github.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subscriptions/CompositeSubscription.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [window](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#window(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) operator (See more information [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#window), search for the version with `window(source, timespan, unit)`).

Your code should be something like this:

```
Observable.window(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).flatmap(...)
```